# VirtualBox screen resolution with Windows 7

Tags: virtualbox, resolution, screen

When I install **Windows 7 32bit** in VirtualBox on Ubuntu 32bit I've got a problem.

The Windows 7 install can't make its resolution equal my notebook screen resolution of **1280x800**.

Comment: ive done the same but still the resolution cannot be changed. the default resolution is 800 X 600 which is greyed out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Installing Guest Additions for Windows** :

The VirtualBox Windows Guest Additions are designed to be installed in a virtual machine running a Windows operating system. The following versions of Windows guests are supported:

> Microsoft Windows NT 4.0 (any service pack)
>
> Microsoft Windows 2000 (any service pack)
>
> Microsoft Windows XP (any service pack)
>
> Microsoft Windows Server 2003 (any service pack)
>
> Microsoft Windows Server 2008
>
> Microsoft Windows Vista (all editions)
>
> Microsoft Windows 7 (all editions)

In the "Devices" menu in the virtual machine's menu bar, VirtualBox has a handy menu item named "Install guest additions", which mounts the Guest Additions ISO file inside your virtual machine. A Windows guest should then automatically start the Guest Additions installer, which installs the Guest Additions into your Windows guest.

SOURCE -> [here](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#additions-windows)

You may need to manually run the Guest Additions executable inside your vm from the mounted cd/iso. Above source instructs how if the iso is unmounted in your vm.

## OR

type in terminal `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-additions`

Comment: There is easy way to install and that is to type `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-additions` from terminal.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the Windows drivers for Virtualbox in the guest. They're called VirtualBox Guest-additions and you'll find it in Virtualbox itself. It'll appear as a CD-rom in your Windows guest.